# how to concatenate two text areas into one paragraph

Tags: javascript

I am trying to concatenate two text areas into a paragraph. The two text areas are where a user can enter data and then push a button and have the results displayed in a paragraph.

I cant figure out why I cant get the two text areas to concatenate into a paragraph html element. I did figure out that I can with the same function have the result shown in an additional text area but when I switch the element back to a paragraph..."p" rather than "textarea" my code no longer functions properly.

javascript:

```
function concatenate(){
    document.getElementById("result1").value =
    document.getElementById("text_area_1").value + " " +
    document.getElementById("text_area_2").value;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="requirement #1">
    <h1> Requirement #1</h1>
    <textarea id="text_area_1"></textarea>
    <textarea id="text_area_2"></textarea>
    <button type="button" id="button1" onclick="concatenate()">concatenate</button>
    <p id="result1"></p
</div>
```

Im not sure why if I change the "p" to a "textarea" element my function works but when I use the "p" tag, it does not work. I think it may have to do with the document.getElementById(...) using ".value" ? maybe I should be using something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`result1` doesn't have a `value` property. It's not a field, it's an [HTMLParagraphElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLParagraphElement). Use [`result1.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) instead.

Of course, you may want to HTML escape the contents of the textarea so that you don't accidentally break your own page, in which case you should use [`result1.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).

Comment: @kronis72 If there's an answer that helped you solve your problem, please click on the checkmark next to it to indicate that you've accepted it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the value for 'result1' properly.

Try this:

```js
function concatenate(){
    //I modified this line, changed .value for .innerHTML
    document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML =
    document.getElementById("text_area_1").value + " " +
    document.getElementById("text_area_2").value;
}
```

```html
<div id="requirement #1">
    <h1> Requirement #1</h1>
    <textarea id="text_area_1"></textarea>
    <textarea id="text_area_2"></textarea>
    <button type="button" id="button1" onclick="concatenate()">concatenate</button>
    <p id="result1"></p
</div>
```